# Java Android Cant seem to update text file using FileOutputStream

Tags: java, android, fileoutputstream

I am a beginner at Android Java development but I have a few years of school + uni experience in Java.
I am trying to write to a text file in an assets folder in my app using FileOutputStream but it doesn't seem to write to it at all since I am using InputStream to read the file after and there haven't any updates.
I am able to read from the same file using inputstream, I just cant write to the file using outputsteam.
Here is my code

```
private void updateTextFile(String update) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try
    {
        fos = openFileOutput("Questions",MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write("Testing".getBytes());
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if(fos!=null)
        {
            try 
            {
                fos.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    String text = "";

    try
    {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("Questions");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        text = new String(buffer);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Tesing output " + text);
}
```

There is nothing in the text file and it just outputs

```
I/System.out: Tesing output
```

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to read or write in `txt` file or `pdf` file?

Comment: I tried writing to a txt but that didn't work either so I tried just a regular file with no results

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you write on a different file and read on a different file.
`openFileOut()` will create a private file based on context.
`getAssets.open()` will get you a file in your app's assets folder.
I think what you want is `InputStream is = openFileInput("Questions");`.

## EDIT

Here an example of `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`.

```
String file = "/storage/emulated/0/test.txt";
OutputStream os = null;
InputStream in = null;
        
try {
    //To write onto a file.
    os = new FileOutputStream(new File(file));
    os.write("This is a test".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    os.flush();
    //To read a file
    in = new FileInputStream(new File(file));
    byte[] store = new byte[8192];
    for(int i; (i=in.read(store, 0, 8192)) != -1; ) {
        System.out.print(new String(store, 0, i, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
    System.out.println();
} catch(IOException e) {
} finally {
    if(os != null) try { os.close(); } catch(Exception ee) {}
    if(in != null) try { in.close(); } catch(Exception ee) {}
}
```

Dont forget set write permission in Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackagename.io"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="4.3" >
    
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
        <uses-permission 
         android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
...
```

Comment: Is there any way to write to the file using InputStream? I am able to read from the same file using inputstream, I just cant write to the file using outputsteam.

Comment: ```Is there any way to write to the file using InputStream?```. Of course not. ```InputStream``` is be used for reading and ```OutputStream``` for writing. Well, I'll update my answer with an example of ``FileInputStream`` and ```FileOutputStream```.

Comment: After reread your comment, I think you want to write into a file in app's assets folder which unfortunately you can't. And no one can. You can however write in local data storage or even internal storage just make sure to set wtite permission in your app's msnifest.